# jEdit: How to turn on syntax highlight for a given extension?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, jedit

I want `.xslt` files to be highlighted as XML in jEdit.

How to do it in jEdit?

Comment: Hmm, mine does it when extension is .xslt but uses xsl mode when extension is .xsl - what does your jedit use for highlighting when you open .xslt? For a single buffer, goto Utilities Menu -> Buffer Options and select xml  from the  Edit Mode dropdown - but I suppose you want a permanent solution

Comment: @StefanHegny Your `xslt` file starts with a proper XML primer which makes jEdit open it as `xml` file. You might want to reconfigure your jEdit though, as there is a dedicated `xsl` mode, but that is only configured to the standard extension `xsl`, as `xslt` is not quite correct as file extension. :-)

Comment: Thx @Vampire, I've been using xslt a lot and most have extension .xsl and no xml primer, so I'm mostly using (and appreciating) the xslt mode. I've no idea why OP would want soth different....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different possible solutions according to what you want.
Besides that, there is an `xsl` mode that you might prefer for `.xslt` files over the `xml` mode. That mode is also the default for `.xsl` files which is the standard extension for XSL(T) scripts.
But as you asked for `xml`, I'll keep with that in the following descriptions.

- If your `.xslt` file starts with an XML header like `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` (actually the important part is the `<?xml` in the beginning), your file is automatically highlighted with the `xml` mode, independent of its name
- If you want to highlight the currently viewed file with a specific mode as long as it stays in the recent files list, just change the mode in the buffer settings, reachable through double click in the status bar on `(<mode>,<wrap>,<encoding>)` or via `Utilities -> Buffer Settings...`
- If you want to highlight a file always with a specific mode, no matter in which jEdit you open it, embed the mode as buffer-local property in the first or last 10 lines of the file like `<!-- :mode=xml: -->`
- If you want to highlight all files that end with `.xslt` with the `xml` mode, you need to edit your mode settings. For this

  - go to `Utilities -> Global Options... -> jEdit -> Editing`
  - select the `xml` mode
  - uncheck `Use default settings`
  - edit the `File name glob` to also match `.xslt` files

Answer (score 1):

**Permanent solution** (assuming linux, you didn't specify a system)

Terminate jedit.

Copy the file `/usr/share/jedit/modes/xml.xml` to your local jedit pref directory under modes/

```
cp /usr/share/jedit/modes/xml.xml ~/.jedit/modes
```

Edit ~/.jedit/modes/catalog so that it looks

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE MODES SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">

<MODES>

<MODE NAME="xml"                FILE="xml.xml"
                                FILE_NAME_GLOB="*.{xml,xhtml,xslt}" />
<!-- Add lines like the following, one for each edit mode you add: -->
<!-- <MODE NAME="foo" FILE="foo.xml" FILE_NAME_GLOB="*.foo" /> -->

</MODES>
```

or to taste, look at the xml/xsl entries in 
`/usr/share/jedit/modes/catalog`

If you are the master of your machine, you can also edit `/usr/share/jedit/modes/catalog` directly and modify the 
 `FILE_NAME_GLOB="*.{xml,`**xslt**`,xhtml,xsd,qrc,ui,docbook}"`
in the MODE NAME="xml" part

Comment: This is a 'little'  overkill. You can simply use the settings dialog. No need for any file manipulations here.

Comment: @Vampire, sure it is i a hack, I probably would have used before going to SO myself, but I see that I get good answers here even for questions not put myself...